# Подобрать неопределенную форму к следующим причастиям:

Tags: причастия, суффиксы, гласные

Помешанный на фантастике ребёнок. (Помешанный - помешать?)
Помешенный для работы бетон. (Помешенный - помесить?)

Answer (score 1):

1) **Помешанный на фантастике ребёнок.** Помешаться — помешанный. Помешаться на ком-чём. Разг. Непомерно увлечься кем-, чем-л., исключительно пристраститься к кому-, чему-л. П. на футболе.

2) Правильно: **замешенный для работы бетон (замесить — замешенный).**

Помешать бетон можно только дополнительно перед работой (помешанный некоторое время), но обычно так не говорят.

ПОМЕШАТЬ, помешанный; св. что. Некоторое время мешать (2.М.; 1 зн.). П. чай. П. суп ложкой. П. угли в печке.

**Помесить бетон (помешенный бетон)**  — это совсем маловероятно, поэтому такой вариант надо считать ошибочным.

ПОМЕСИТЬ, -мешу, -месишь; помешенный; -шен, -а, -о; св. что. Месить некоторое время. П. тесто. П. глину.

**О бетоне**

Как приготовить бетон:

**1) замесить бетон**

ЗАМЕСИТЬ,  замешенный; св. (нсв. также месить). что. Приготовить однородную вязкую массу, размешивая, растирая что-л. в воде (в жидкости). З. тесто. З. глину.

Правильно **замешенный** бетон после затвердевания отличается высокой прочностью.

2) **размешать составляющие бетона, в том числе жидкие**

РАЗМЕШАТЬ, (нсв. также мешать). что. Мешая, растворить, развести, равномерно распределить в чём-л. жидком или сыпучем. Р. сахар в чае. Р. муку в воде. Р. гущу.

Как **размешать** небольшое количество бетона?

Comment: Существует ли причастие *помешенный*?

Comment: В словаре есть: ПОМЕСИТЬ, -мешу, -месишь; помешенный; -шен, -а, -о; св. что. Месить некоторое время. П. тесто. П. глину.  Но на практике  оно вряд ли применяется. Например: помесить тесто 5 минут, помешенное тесто отложить в сторону.  Не думаю, что такой текст может быть актуальным.

Comment: Да, *помешенное тесто* есть на учебных сайтах, но я такого не нашел в реальных текстах.

Comment: Тесто месят, а бетон замешивают, в процессе изготовления и по дороге к заказчику бетон (точнее, бетонную смесь) перемешивают.   Я тоже думаю, что неверно говорить, что бетон месят (месить, помесить, помешенный).

Comment: Скорее всего, это ошибка составителей задания. А школьникам надо быть внимательнее, они, как мне кажется, часто выполняют такие задания механически. Так вот и теряется интерес к родному языку.